# How to represent comma's in string?

Tags: c#, string

I have a integer like this i.e `3356890`. I'm converting it to string and showing on screen.
Now I want to display like this `3,356,890`.

How to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
value = 1234567890;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0,0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); 
// Displays 1,234,567,890
```

However, for the purpose of [internationalization and localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization), it's probably best to allow the user's current culture settings to determine how to format the number.

**Further Reading**

- [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look please here,
[Number string format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
string res = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:#,##0}", 3356890);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int val = 3356890;

string valString = val.ToString("#,##0")
```